# Optimized alternative code for the function to reverse input string word by word in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
alter FUNCTION FlipName(@input VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @i int ,@add varchar(255)
set @i=1
set @add=''
declare @work varchar(250)
set @work=''
WHILE @i <= len(@input)
BEGIN
  declare @pivot varchar(255)
  set @pivot=SUBSTRING(@input,@i,1)
  while @pivot <>' '
  begin
     set @add=@add+@pivot
     set @i=@i+1
     set @pivot=SUBSTRING(@input,@i,1)
  end

  set @work=@add+' '+@work 
  set @add=''

  SET @i = @i + 1

END
return @work
END
```

> Sample Input: My name is Jarvis
>
> Sample Output:Jarvis is name My

I am looking for **better,shorter and more concise alternative code** to this as the nested loops here are performance killers.

I am looking for a better workaround without loops maybe

Please provide a concise explanation to your solution stating how is it better.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The sensible alternative is to not be doing string manipulation in a language such as T-SQL which is notoriously weak in terms of its support for string manipulation. Why does this code belong in the database *at all*?

Comment: Having a `WHILE` loop **inside** a `WHILE` loop is going to also be awful for performance. SQL Server is terrible at iterative processes; it's far better at set based processes.

Comment: I agree T-SQL isn't the best language for doing string manipulation.Having said that i am just looking for better alternative solution to the above scalar function

Comment: @Larnu Yes, that is why i am here looking for some alternative workaround to achieve this without nested loop.

Comment: One thing about these sorts of codings, is that you've always got to be careful to code for (or validate input), for various odd boundary conditions, things like leading and trailing spaces, words with >1 spaces between them.  What happens then?  Always best to test that.

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL is not best solution for string manipulation. But it could be done without loop at all (SQL Server 2017+):

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'My name is Jarvis';

SELECT @s, STRING_AGG(value, ' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rn DESC)
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)AS rn
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@s, ' ', '.'), '.'))s;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd25b1fbc345ed5c401baa94f9a937e9)**

Comment: And don't forget, when you create this as a function use a Table-Value function, not a scalar function.

Comment: Thanks.Great Solution, But as Larnu pointed out that STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG are more recently added function and would not be supported by previous versions

Comment: Nice solution but this is not guaranteed to work.  We have to wait for `split_string()` to provide an ordinality column as well as the string part.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that ordinal position is important here (something that `STRING_SPLIT` doesn't return), and that `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` are more recently added function, you could use [`delimitedsplit8k`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and `FOR XML PATH`. This means that the order is guaranteed (as `delimitedsplit8k` returns the ordinal position) and it means you don't need SQL Server 2017:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReverseString_fn (@input varchar(255))
RETURNS table AS
RETURN

    SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' ' + DS.Item
                  FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@input,' ') DS
                  ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber DESC
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ReverseString;
GO

WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT 'My name is Jarvis' AS String)
SELECT *
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY dbo.ReverseString_fn(V.String) RS;
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.ReverseString_fn;
```

Comment: Great!! Could you provide me with code demo as this also seems to NOT be running on my SQL server 2014

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 "Seems to not be running"? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? The above is a demo. It creates the function and then uses it.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to some online IDE where you tested this code as I am not able to run this on SQL14 and azure

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 again, what do you able "not able to run"? If you can't execute the query, I would suggest you don't have permission to `CREATE` on your database; as that's the first statement in the batch. Again, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: >Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReverseString_fn, Line 7
>Invalid object name 'dbo.DelimitedSplit8K'.
>Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>Invalid object name 'dbo.ReverseString_fn'.
>Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 19
>Cannot drop the function 'dbo.ReverseString_fn', because it does not exist or >you do not have permission.  P.S-I have not down voted.

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 Seems you haven't created `dbo.DelimitedSplit8K`. Have you clicked the link I provided?

Comment: I've love to hear some constructive feedback from the downvote, please.

Comment: As for why I didn't provide a DB Fiddle, or similar, that's because I am citing a function designed by Jeff Moden. I doubt they would be happy for me to put their work in a DB Fiddle. You would be much better off reading their article I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174156/discussion-between-alamshahbaz16497-and-larnu).

Answer (score 1):

and yet one more... The following approach is fully inline and uses an *on-the-fly* tally table in connection with XML's ability to fetch an element by its position:

```sql
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100)='My name is Jarvis';

WITH Casted(inputXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @input AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)
,Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT inputXml.value('count(/x)','int') FROM Casted) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' ' + c.inputXml.value('(/x[sql:column("t.Nmbr")]/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
    FROM Tally t
    CROSS JOIN Casted c
    ORDER BY t.Nmbr DESC
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'
),1,1,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest doing it in backend. 
But for a work around(**below SQL Server 2016**) you can have below code.
You can make a function with the below code and call it on table rows.

```
DECLARE @VAL VARCHAR(MAX) ='My name is Jarvis', @NEW_VAL VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @VAL = '<M>'+ REPLACE(@VAL, ' ','</M><M>')+'</M>';

SELECT @NEW_VAL = @NEW_VAL+ ' ' + NEW_TEXT FROM ( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) SNO, 
 splt.x.value('.','varchar(100)') NEW_TEXT FROM (
SELECT CAST(@VAL AS XML) AS DATA
)AS A
CROSS APPLY DATA.nodes('/M') as splt(x)
)B
ORDER BY SNO DESC;

SELECT @NEW_VAL
```

Result:

```
 Jarvis is name My
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reverse string word by word then you can use following optimized code for it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ReverseWordsInSentence]
(
    @ip VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @op VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @op = ''
    DECLARE @Lenght INT

    WHILE LEN(@ip) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(' ', @ip) > 0
        BEGIN
        SET @op = SUBSTRING(@ip,0,CHARINDEX(' ', @ip)) + ' ' + @op
        SET @ip = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ip,CHARINDEX(' ', @ip) + 1,LEN(@ip))))
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @op = @ip + ' ' + @op
        SET @ip = ''
        END
    END
RETURN @op
END
```

You execute this function with the input string you mentioned as follows.

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_ReverseWordsInSentence] ('My name is Jarvis')
```

And this will return following string as output.

"Jarvis is name My"

If you just want reverse entire string character by character then you can use Sql Server in built reverse string function.

```
DECLARE @test varchar(250) = 'My name is Jarvis'

SELECT reverse(@test)
```

And this will return "sivraJ si eman yM" as output.

Comment: A `WHILE` loop is still a bad choice here.

Comment: @Larnu: the answer give solution but way is little bit wrong, so there should no down vote for it

Comment: @SandipPatel this thing is, `WHILE` loops are notorious slow in SQL Server. `WHILE` loops and `CURSOR`s are misused a lot, especially when doing something that should be set based. Can you imagine how slow this would be against a table with 1,000 or so rows? It would require 1,000 (or so) `WHILE` loops (as this would have to be a scalar function), each iterating over **every** character in **every**`varchar`. That is never going to perform well.

Comment: @Larnu: as I told the answer little bit wrong way, but the solution is right. From my point of view the solution of any question comes first then after other things which you can improve as you got experience.

Comment: @SandipPatel but the OP is looking for concise, and faster, code, and they've stated (in the comments) they looking for a method with a loop, wouldn't a loop therefore be the wrong choice? Especially when they are so frowned upon when there is a set-based solution. :) Yes, the answer is "right(ish)", however, that doesn't m,ake it a good answer. String Splitters that use `WHILE` loops and `CURSOR` are "correct" answers, but they're also very bad ones, when far better approaches are available.

Comment: I would go a step further, string splitter that use loops are not correct answers because they are so slow. There are many set based splitters available all over the place that using one with a loop is just awful. Even though this answer returns the correct data the approach is so painfully slow it needs to be downvoted or other people may think it is ok to use loops for this kind of thing.